# pyspark error: AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'serializer'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark ver 2.0.1

```
def f(l):
    print(l.b_appid)

sqlC=SQLContext(spark)
mrdd = sqlC.read.parquet("hdfs://localhost:54310/yogi/device/processed//data.parquet")
mrdd.forearch(f) <== this gives error
```

Answer (score 4):

In `Spark 2.X` - in order to use `Spark Session` (aka `spark`) you need to create it

You can create `SparkSession`like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
     .builder \
     .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
     .getOrCreate()
```

Once you have the `SparkSession` object (`spark`) you can use it like this:

```
mydf = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://localhost:54310/yogi/device/processed//data.parquet")
mydf.forearch(f)
```

**More info can be found in [Spark Sessions section in spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession):**

> **class pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sparkContext, jsparkSession=None)**
>
> The entry point to programming Spark with the Dataset and DataFrame
>   API. A SparkSession can be used create DataFrame, register DataFrame
>   as tables, execute SQL over tables, cache tables, and read parquet
>   files. To create a SparkSession, use the following builder pattern:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Word Count") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Info about class builder can be found in **[class Builder - Builder for SparkSession.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder)**